# Get the Common data from the List

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I have the below List in C#.

[image]

I need to generate the below data.

1. In one row, all the users and apps they have in common for the particular Department, Profile, and Role
2. In the 2nd row, each user has a unique application that is not included in the 1st row.

Below is the output I need.

[image]

**Please Can anyone help here?**

Below are the details.

**Class:**

```
class UserData
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Workstations { get; set; }
    public string Applications { get; set; }
}
```

**List:**

```
List<UserData> tempList = new List<UserData>
            {
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="Z", Workstations="3", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="Z", Workstations="3", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Office" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="PDF" },
                new UserData {Department="A", Role="B", Profile="C", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Test" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="Z", Workstations="3", Applications="Skype" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="Z", Workstations="3", Applications="Teams" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="Office" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="X", Workstations="1", Applications="PDF" },
                new UserData {Department="D", Role="E", Profile="F", User="Y", Workstations="2", Applications="Test" }
            };
```

**Here is my Solution:**

```
List<UserData> CommonList = new List<UserData>();
List<UserData> UnCommonList = new List<UserData>();

   var UniqueUsers = tempList.GroupBy(r => new { r.User, r.Department, r.Profile, r.Role, })
                                                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.User).Distinct().ToList();

            var UniqueApplications = tempList.GroupBy(r => new { r.Applications, r.Department, r.Profile, r.Role, })
                                                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Applications).ToList();

            foreach (var app in UniqueApplications)
            {
                var usersForApp = tempList.Where(x => x.Applications.Equals(app.Key.Applications) && x.Department.Equals(app.Key.Department) && x.Profile.Equals(app.Key.Profile) && x.Role.Equals(app.Key.Role)).Distinct().ToList();
                var usersGroup = UniqueUsers.GroupBy(r => new { r.Key.User, r.Key.Department, r.Key.Profile, r.Key.Role, })
                                                        .Where(x => x.Key.Department.Equals(app.Key.Department) && x.Key.Profile.Equals(app.Key.Profile) && x.Key.Role.Equals(app.Key.Role))
                                                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.User).Distinct().ToList();

                if (usersForApp != null)
                {
                    if(usersForApp.Count() == usersGroup.Count())
                    {
                        CommonList.AddRange(usersForApp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UnCommonList.AddRange(usersForApp);

                    }
                }
            }
            var FinalCommon = CommonList.GroupBy(ac => new
            {
                ac.Department, 
                ac.Profile,
                ac.Role
            })
                    .Select(ac => new UserData
                    {
                        Department = ac.Key.Department,
                        Profile = ac.Key.Profile,
                        Role = ac.Key.Role,
                        User = string.Join(",", ac.Select(y => y.User).ToList().Distinct().ToArray()),
                        Applications = string.Join(",", ac.Select(y => y.Applications).Distinct().ToList().ToArray())
                    }).ToList();

            var FinalUnCommon = UnCommonList.GroupBy(ac => new
            {
                ac.Department,
                ac.Profile,
                ac.Role,
                ac.User
            })
                   .Select(ac => new UserData
                   {
                       Department = ac.Key.Department,
                       Profile = ac.Key.Profile,
                       Role = ac.Key.Role,
                       User = ac.Key.User,
                       Applications = string.Join(",", ac.Select(y => y.Applications).Distinct().ToList().ToArray())
                   }).ToList();
```

Can anyone help me to use Linq to avoid the looping?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you showed us what you tried and describe what didn't work/ output?

Comment: _I tried grouping and all but not able to get the desired output._ - show what you tried and what you meant by "not able to get the desired result"? Did you get some exception or what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. It is not a single LINQ statement though.

```
// find out what applications are common
var firstPass = tempList.GroupBy(g => new
{
    g.Department,
    g.Role,
    g.Profile,
    g.User,
    g.Workstations
}).Select(g => new
{
    g.Key,
    Applications = g.Select(o => o.Applications)
});

var distinctGroupsCount = firstPass.Count();

// assume if an application repeats this amount it is available everywhere

var appsEveryoneHas = tempList.GroupBy(s => s.Applications)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == distinctGroupsCount)
    .Select(s => s.Key)
    .ToHashSet();
  

var finalResult = tempList
    .GroupBy(g => new
    {
        g.Department, 
        g.Role, 
        g.Profile, 
        User = appsEveryoneHas.Contains(g.Applications) ? string.Empty : g.User
    }).
    Select(s => new UserData
    {
        Department = s.First().Department,
        Role = s.First().Role,
        Profile = s.First().Profile,
        Workstations = string.Join(',', s.Select(o => o.Workstations).Distinct()),
        User = string.Join(',', s.Select(o => o.User).Distinct()),
        Applications = string.Join(',', s.Select(o => o.Applications).Distinct())
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This satisfies the first row successfully but in the 2nd row, what I want is for each user there should be separate row. So for example if there is a new record for User Y with same Application or different application then it should be new row.
I don't want to merge the users or application if they are not common in all the users.

Comment: @dhruvil29, modified the GroupBy based on your feedback. Hope this helps.